# Sleep in javascript (or equivalent)

Tags: javascript, delay, wait

How do I wait 1 second before executing next function?

For example like php has sleep()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a sleep function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141302/is-there-a-sleep-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Answer (score 5):

`setTimeout(f, 1000);`

Set a timeout to run a function after 1000 milliseconds

[`window.setTimeout`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

[`window.setTimeout`<sup>*[spec]*</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout)

[`window.setTimeout`<sup>*[dark side]*</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536753(v=vs.85).aspx)

As mentioned in the comments. JavaScript is single threaded and that thread is shared with the browser UI thread.

So by calling a blocking function like `sleep`. You would block the *only* thread. This also means that the client cannot interact with the page whilst it is blocking.

See the [Event Driven Programming<sup>*[wiki]*</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) article for more information

Comment: To expand that: you don't want something like "sleep" because you don't want the browser to stop operating while you wait. Because Javascript is event-driven, you need to hand back control to the browser and tell it to wake you up after the requisite time.

Answer (score 1):

Even though setTimeout is supported in all major browsers, I prefer to use a javascript library because usually one is doing more js than just calling a timeout function.  In YUI its:

```
YAHOO.lang.later(1000, this, function() {
...
});
```

More information [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.lang.html#method_later).

Comment: Why prefer to use a library for this. It seems ridiculous to include a library just for this.

Comment: @Ryanos really!? Odds have it if the guy is using setTimeout he's probably doing more js than just calling the function to sleep for 1 second. It's good practice, plus YUI and others abstract away some complexity like interval calling.  Stop being so trigger happy and go get a coffee

Comment: that's a different issue. There's a difference between recommending a library for browser compliance (always good) and recommending a library to solve a very specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeOut method to do so
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

> setTimeout("alertMsg()",1000);
>
> function alertMsg() { 
>     alert("Hello"); 
>   }

Comment: The specifics of this example are also unhelpful: It's considered bad practice to pass a string as the first argument to `setTimeout`, as it evaluates to `setTimeout(function() { eval("myFunction()"); }, 3000)`. `timeMsg` assigns the timeout handle to t, but never returns it, so there's no way to clear the timeout. It also is tightly coupled to `alertMsg` because it's using a magic string as an execution callback.