# How to delay before close() and redirect?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a sleep function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141302/is-there-a-sleep-function-in-javascript)

How can i add a delay to this to make it close and redirect after so many seconds please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { parent.$.fancybox.close(); });
  window.parent.location.href = '/shop/basket';
</script>
```

Comment: whats the point in closing anything when instant redirecting ?

Comment: @jAndy: The question asks ` make it close **and** redirect after so many seconds`

Comment: @jAndy one can only assume that fancybox's close function does something else important? :)

Comment: @jAndy: So clearly they want to close **and** redirect.

Comment: @MattBurland: actually my point was.. if the *close* and *redirect* happens at the same time, closing doesn't make much sense. I could buy it if you want to *close* a box, wait a little and then redirect.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.closeAndRedirect = function() {
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
    window.parent.location.href = '/shop/basket';
}

setTimeout(closeAndRedirect, 5000); // 5 seconds
```

@jAndy pointed out: why would you want to close something if you are redirecting anyway?, which is a valid point.

maybe you meant close, THEN redirect 5 seconds after closing? If so:

```
parent.$.fancybox.close(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       window.parent.location.href = '/shop/basket';
    });
});
```

assuming that close has a callback. If not, maybe:

```
parent.$.fancybox.close();
setTimeout(function() {
    window.parent.location.href = '/shop/basket';
});
```

Comment: Why keep the jQuery `$(document).ready()`? After 5 seconds, if the DOM isn't already loaded, it'll just redirect straight away anyway.

Comment: good point. my oversight due to copying and pasting :). I made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and call your function from the callback.

Something like:

```
$(function() { 
    setTimeout(function() {
        parent.$.fancybox.close(); 
        window.parent.location.href = '/shop/basket';
    }, 5000);
});
```

to wait 5 seconds, start from when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to do that from within the opened (child) page but directly on the **parent** page.... just use `setTimeout` inside a callback in your custom fancybox script to program the *close* and *redirection* tasks like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.fancybox.close();
            window.location.href = "/shop/basket";
        }, 5000); // 5000 = 5 secs
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yzr7H/)**