# How can I write a function that takes X amount of seconds?

Tags: javascript, delay, sleep

I want to write a javascript function that takes very close to 5 seconds to run. How can I make that guarantee?

I have tried

```
  function wait(numSeconds) {
    var end = new Date().getMilliseconds() + numSeconds * 1000;
    while (new Date().getMilliseconds() <= end) {}
  }
```

but this just crashes the page.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141302/is-there-a-sleep-function-in-javascript

Comment: Implementing a `wait()`, `pause()` or `sleep()` function is a big JS no-no. Whatever you're trying to achieve can likely be done with `setTimeout()` instead.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You probably want to delay some code execution? For that see setTimeout and setInterval functions.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe `setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},5000);` is the solution here.

Comment: I am writing a javascript timer that lets you time how long functions run. I want to test it by writing a function that actually takes about 5 seconds.

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @DavidFaux: Then just do something like this: http://jsbin.com/igiyih/5/edit - the only thing that is required for the function you want to time is that it takes an argument `callback` which it calls when its done doing what it needs to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
var t = setTimeout(function(){alert('done')},5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot freeze the page without freezing the page.

You're trying to write a function that runs for 5 seconds straight.
Javascript runs on the UI thread, so the page will be frozen whenever any code runs.

In short, you can't do that.
You need to write *asynchronous code*, probably by using `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait 5 seconds before doing something, use [setTimeout or setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).  Otherwise, just eating up user time is a bad idea.  In fact, the browsers will interrupt your script if it takes too long to do something, which your function most certainly will do.

Answer (score 2):

(Ignoring for the moment why you shouldn't really do this...)

The reason your code is freezing the browser is that your `while` condition will *never* become true (for `numSeconds` of 1 or more).

The [`.getMilliseconds()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FgetMilliseconds) returns *just* the milliseconds part of the date, i.e., a number between 0 and 999. For `numSeconds` of 1 of more your `end` will always be greater than 999.

Try using [`.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FgetTime) instead of `.getMilliseconds()`. Or if you don't care about supporting old browsers uses [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2Fnow).

Answer (score 1):

You could just use javascripts setTimeout instead of your own wait function.

setTimeout excecutes a function after a certain amount of time.

For example:

```
setTimeout(function(){}, 5000);
```

Would just wait 5 seconds.

See more at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, what you ask cannot be done because, as you've seen, the page will freeze while you wait.

As a practical matter, though, I suspect that what you really want is the something like this:

```
function waitawhile() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        alert('5 seconds has passed');
    }, 5000);
}
```