# Toggle JavaScript OnClick function seconds after seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

On my submit button, I have `onclick="list_activity();` but how can I make the `list_activity();` function run about 2 seconds after the button is clicked instead of straight away?

HTML code I'm using:

```
<textarea name="blab_field" id="blab_field" style="width:98%;height:55px;" placeholder="What is on your mind?  - What are you doing right now? - Tag people with @username (username can be found on profiles)"></textarea>

          <input name="mem_id" id="mem_id" type="hidden" value="4" />
          <input name="poster_id" id="poster_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $logOptions_id; ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" value="a" />
          <input type="hidden" name="device" id="device" value="Google Chrome : Windows 7" />
           <input name="submit" type="submit" style="width:100%;" onClick="post_chat();" class="btn btn-info" value="Post Blab" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(){
     setTimeout(list_activity, 2000);                    
}});
```

**UPDATES:**

**HTML:**

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" style="width:100%;" onClick="post_chat();" class="btn btn-info" value="Post Blab" />
```

**JS:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function post_chat() {
        setTimeout(list_activity, 2000); 
            //your todos
    }

    function list_activity() {
        //your todos 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: This actually adds the function to every `input` of type `submit`. Not a good solution!

Comment: Under `<script type="text/javascript>`

Comment: What's the better solution?

Comment: @James you can't have like this.  onClick="post_chat();setTimeout(list_activity(), 2000);"  Let me give you a nice way.

Comment: @user1671639: It doesn´t matter. Don´t solve tasks for the global scope, if not explicitly ask for. Please edit your answer!

Comment: @user1671639 Thank you :) What is the nice way then?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [**setTimeout()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet after specified delay.

Your `list_activity` function should like

```
function list_activity (
        setTimeout(function () {
                              formid.submit();
                        }, 2000);                    
                  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it.

```
setTimeout(function() { your_function(); }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have it in a `setTimeout`:

```
onclick="setTimeout(list_activity, 2000);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the SetTimeOut method can be usefull to you :

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 3000);// if you have defined a function named myFunction it will run after 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds)
```

You can see a really good explanation of how to delay your code here : [see the SolutionYogi response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141302/is-there-a-sleep-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

```
onclick="setTimeout(list_activity(), 2000);"
```

Comment: @KaushalDeSilva I'm have not downvoted.  It should be `setTimeout(list_activity, 2000)` no need of ()

Comment: My bad. I'll leave it here as is, so people can see the problem vs. the correct method.