# Concurrent actions with setInterval and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, concurrency, settimeout, setinterval

I'm a JavaScript newbie and I'm trying to achieve concurrent actions with `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.

What I'd like to achieve, what actually happens and what I expected to happen is best explained with the following code.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
  myTimer()
}, 1000);

function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("log " + i);
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

My expectation for the leading `setInterval`, is that the function `myTimer` is executed every second, independent of what happens afterwards. Except of course if the site is closed or `clearTimeout` is called on the `myVar`.

I can not verify if this action really happens independently and in an ongoing manner.

The following for loop, is there to simulate further code, to see if the `myTimer` function would be executed independently.

I expected the loop to start with `i=0`, then wait for three seconds, log `log 0` to the console, then continue with `i=1` and so on.

Instead it appears that the timeout is started and in the meantime `i` has reached the end of the for loop and is therefore `100`.

How do I get the for loop to wait with the iteration for the `setTimeout`?

And is the `setInterval` really executed every second, independent of the following code? E.g. if the following code had actions that take some processing/time, would the clock update anyways, during the processing?

Comment: you might have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: I'll go over that, thanks. If I understand it correctly it concerns with the iteration and the `i` variable. Do you have a comment about my questions on `setInterval` and `setTimeout`?

Comment: You might also  find this useful [Is there a sleep function in JavaScript?] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141302/is-there-a-sleep-function-in-javascript). It looks like you are trying to suspend execution using the settimeout - but that  won't work because settimeout doesn't block execution, it defers it by putting the callback on the event queue to be executed at a later time - the current turn then immediately continues.

Comment: Thanks @BobGear, that explains my issue with `setTimeout`. Is `setInterval` *asynchronous* as well, so that it runs independently of the rest of the code?

Comment: My  under standing is that it is - every time the interval fires, the callback executes *and* another item is put on the event loop ready for it to be fired the next time the interval expires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the timeout time with the factor of `i` and use a closure over `i` to get the right value.

```js
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

var i,
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(function (i) {
        return function() {
            console.log("log " + i);
        };
    }(i), 3000 * i);
}
```

```html
<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

A version with calling timeout after timeout.

```js
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
}

function next() {
    i++;
    console.log("log " + i);
    if (i < 300) {
        setTimeout(next, 3000);
    }
}

var i = 0,
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

setTimeout(next, 3000);
```

```html
<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This works exactly like I intended/expected my code to, but I can't really wrap my head around how this works. So you run a function, in `setTimeout`, which `return`s a function, which runs the `console.log`? and you multiply the timeout time by 3000 ms for every `i`? Sorry - I'm lost.

Comment: right. the closure over `i` keeps the value and the multiplication with i delays the call of the returned function.

Comment: Does that mean that the for loop runs immediately through all 100 `i`s and each log is actually kept *somewhere* on hold, until the 3 seconds * `i` have expired, then it's executed?

Comment: right. for a different approach, you could chain the interval, where each function sets an interval in 3000 ms for the next.

Comment: This is so confusing, coming from other languages. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

About your `setInterval` question, yes. It will run every second (not being millisecond scrupulous). let's say you just set your `setInterval`, and then run an action that takes half a second to run. The interval will count that half second and run after another half second. Hard code will not delay the clock, **BUT**, if you are running code just in the moment that the interval should fire, it will wait for that code to end, as JavaScript is single threaded. This means that if right after setting your interval you run code that lasts more than 1 second, the interval callback will be ran after it, so it will not be fired in 1 second. By the way, subsequent interval calls will be called not after this interval, but after the interval was set. Check this fiddle (F12): https://jsfiddle.net/0gggmemu/4/

You see that the first interval is called when the code ends, but subsequent intervals are called counting when the interval was set (check milliseconds, how they fit the first log instead of the start one). Note that the intervals are not stacked. If it should have called 10 intervals, it will only call one and wait for the next. If time precision is important for you, then you should save a reference at startup and check the difference in each interval.

About concurrency, the same as when you call `setInterval`, when you call `setTimeout` the code will continue its execution, creating a hundred of timeouts at the same time. If you want code to hang just check my fiddle. By the way, if your worry is about `setTimeout` locking `setInterval`, don't worry, as the code will not be blocked. You only have to semi-worry if you have code that gets stuck somewhere, but in a callback-driven application is kinda difficult to achieve this.