# Is there a better way for sleep function in javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I wish you all having a great day.
I am working on this project for a game and I want in case of winning that it waits for 2 seconds before returning to the start point I using this code to do just

```
function sleep(delay) {
var start = new Date().getTime();
while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay);
}
```

which I got from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758214/8072569)
anyhow , the problem with this is that the game freziz for the number seconds 
you can say in this picutre [image: it's stuck for 2 seconds]
My question is is there is more effichent way to do so I have tryied also `setTimeOut()`but it's the same problem

> EDIT : 
>   This Is the Solution is great and work perfectly, Thanks a lot
>   [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951057/8072569)

```
    function sleep (time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
    }

sleep(500).then(() => {
// Do something after the sleep!
});
```

Comment: For a game you don't want the waiting time to block all of your UI (the freeze you are talking about), so your sleep needs to be somehow asynchronous. It's something to keep in mind for the overall architecture of your pgrogram. Without understanding the architecture of your app, it's hard to guide you correctly. Namely, you don't provide a [mcve] that shows this freeze so we can work on.

Comment: The 2nd answer in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1141340/797194) pretty much sums up why you cannot have non-freezing "sleep" in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout for this purpose.

```
deactivateGame();

setTimeout(function(){

    activateGame()
}, 2000)
```

In the above example, the `activateGame` and `deactivateGame` functions will place some indicators over your game to tell the user that the game is waiting.